TypeError: Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'registerContractor') in My Ethereum DApp
I'm encountering a TypeError: Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'registerContractor') when trying to call the registerContractor function on my smart contract using the ethers.js library.
The error occurs in my frontend code where I'm interacting with the smart contract. The function seems undefined on the contract instance, but it is correctly implemented in Solidity.
Solidity Code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// Main contract for decentralized tendering system

//hello shureed
contract BidChain {
    // Structure to store contractor details
    struct Contractor {
        address contractorAddress; // Contractor's Ethereum address
        string companyName;        // Contractor's company name
        string email;              // Contractor's email address
        bool isRegistered;         // Registration status of contractor (whether registered or not)
    }

    // Structure to store tender details (only one tender active at a time in this contract)
    struct Tender {
        string description;        // Description of the tender
        string noticeDocumentHash; // IPFS hash of the tender notice document
        uint256 submissionEndTime; // Deadline for bid submissions
        bool isOpen;               // Indicates if the tender is open for bids
        address winner;            // Winner's address after evaluation
    }

    // Structure to store bid details
    struct Bid {
        uint256 amount;     // Bid amount offered by contractor
        string ipfsHash;    // IPFS hash for the encrypted bid document
        bool submitted;     // Status to check if the bid is submitted
        bool isWinner;      // Status to indicate if the bid is the winning one
    }

    // Contract owner (usually the principal or tender initiator)
    address public owner;

    // Active tender instance (only one tender active at a time in this contract)
    Tender public activeTender;

    // Mapping to store registered contractors with their address
    mapping(address => Contractor) public contractors;               

    // Mapping to store bid submitted by contractors
    mapping(address => Bid) public bids;

    // Mapping to store pending contractor registration requests
    mapping(address => Contractor) public pendingContractors;

    // Array to store the list of addresses that have submitted registration requests
    address[] public addressList;

    // Array to store addresses of all bidders in the current tender
    address[] public bidderAddresses;

    // Events
    event ContractorRegistered(address contractorAddress, string companyName, string email);
    event ContractorRegistrationRequested(address contractorAddress, string companyName, string email);
    event TenderOpened(string description, string noticeDocumentHash, uint256 endTime);
    event BidSubmitted(address indexed contractor, uint256 amount, string ipfsHash);
    event WinnerAnnounced(address indexed winner, uint256 winningBid, string winnerDocumentHash);

    // Modifier to restrict function access to contract owner
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not authorized"); // Ensure caller is the owner
        _;
    }

    // Modifier to restrict function access to registered contractors only
    modifier onlyRegisteredContractor() {
        require(contractors[msg.sender].isRegistered, "Contractor not registered"); // Ensure caller is registered
        _;
    }

    // Modifier to ensure the tender is open for submissions
    modifier tenderOpen() {
        require(block.timestamp <= activeTender.submissionEndTime && activeTender.isOpen, "Tender closed"); // Check if tender is open
        _;
    }

    // Constructor to set the contract owner at deployment
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender; // Set owner to the account deploying the contract
    }


    // Function to retrieve the owner of the contract
    function getContractOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner; // Return the contract owner
    }


    // Submit a registration request (contractor only)
    function submitRegistrationRequest(string memory _companyName, string memory _email) external {
        require(pendingContractors[msg.sender].contractorAddress == address(0), "Registration request already submitted"); // Check if the contractor already submitted a request
        pendingContractors[msg.sender] = Contractor(msg.sender, _companyName, _email, false); // Store pending registration details
        addressList.push(msg.sender); // Add contractor address to the list
        emit ContractorRegistrationRequested(msg.sender, _companyName, _email); // Emit event that registration request has been submitted
    }

    // Admin can check pending contractors
    function getPendingContractors() external view onlyOwner returns (Contractor[] memory) {
        uint256 pendingCount = 0;

        // Count the number of pending contractors
        for (uint i = 0; i < addressList.length; i++) {
            if (pendingContractors[addressList[i]].contractorAddress != address(0)) {
                pendingCount++; // Increment if a pending request exists for that address
            }
        }

        // Create an array to hold all pending contractors
        Contractor[] memory pending = new Contractor[](pendingCount);
        uint256 index = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < addressList.length; i++) {
            if (pendingContractors[addressList[i]].contractorAddress != address(0)) {
                pending[index] = pendingContractors[addressList[i]]; // Add pending contractors to the array
                index++;
            }
        }

        return pending; // Return the array of pending contractors
    }

    // Admin can register a contractor
    function registerContractor(address _contractorAddress) external onlyOwner {
        // Ensure the contractor has a registration request pending
        require(pendingContractors[_contractorAddress].contractorAddress != address(0), "Contractor not found");
        // Get the contractor details from the pendingContractors mapping
        Contractor memory contractor = pendingContractors[_contractorAddress];
        // Mark the contractor as registered
        contractors[_contractorAddress] = contractor;
        // Remove from the pendingContractors list
        delete pendingContractors[_contractorAddress]; // Remove from pending list after registration

        // Emit the ContractorRegistered event with the contractor's details
        emit ContractorRegistered(_contractorAddress, contractor.companyName, contractor.email);
    }

    // Function to open a new tender, accessible by owner only
    function openTender(string memory _description, string memory _noticeDocumentHash, uint256 _duration) external onlyOwner {
        require(!activeTender.isOpen, "Tender already open"); // Ensure no tender is currently open
        // Set up new tender details
        activeTender = Tender({
            description: _description,
            noticeDocumentHash: _noticeDocumentHash,
            submissionEndTime: block.timestamp + _duration, // Set end time based on duration
            isOpen: true,
            winner: address(0) // No winner yet
        });

        emit TenderOpened(_description, _noticeDocumentHash, activeTender.submissionEndTime); // Emit tender opened event
    }

    // Function for registered contractors to submit their bid
    function submitBid(uint256 _amount, string memory _ipfsHash) external onlyRegisteredContractor tenderOpen {
        require(!bids[msg.sender].submitted, "Bid already submitted"); // Check if bid is already submitted

        // Store the bid details in the mapping
        bids[msg.sender] = Bid({
            amount: _amount,
            ipfsHash: _ipfsHash,
            submitted: true,
            isWinner: false
        });

        bidderAddresses.push(msg.sender); // Add contractor to list of bidders

        emit BidSubmitted(msg.sender, _amount, _ipfsHash); // Emit bid submitted event
    }

    // Announce the winner
    function announceWinner(address _winner) external onlyOwner {
        require(block.timestamp > activeTender.submissionEndTime, "Tender submission still open"); // Ensure submission period has ended
        require(activeTender.isOpen, "No active tender"); // Ensure there is an active tender

        bids[_winner].isWinner = true; // Mark the winning bid
        activeTender.isOpen = false; // Close the tender
        activeTender.winner = _winner; // Set the winner's address

        emit WinnerAnnounced(_winner, bids[_winner].amount, bids[_winner].ipfsHash); // Emit event with the winner details
    }

    // View function to get details of the winner's bid
    function getWinnerDetails() external view returns (address, uint256, string memory) {
        return (activeTender.winner, bids[activeTender.winner].amount, bids[activeTender.winner].ipfsHash); // Return winner's address, bid amount, and IPFS hash
    }

    // View function to get the IPFS hash of a specific contractor's bid
    function getBidIPFSHash(address _contractor) external view returns (string memory) {
        require(bids[_contractor].submitted, "Bid not submitted"); // Ensure bid was submitted
        return bids[_contractor].ipfsHash; // Return IPFS hash of the bid document
    }

    // Utility function to retrieve all bidder addresses in the current tender
    function getBidderAddresses() external view returns (address[] memory) {
        return bidderAddresses; // Return the array of bidder addresses
    }


    // View function to allow registered contractors to see the notice document hash of the active tender
    function viewNoticeDocumentHash() external view onlyRegisteredContractor returns (string memory) {
        require(activeTender.isOpen, "No active tender"); // Ensure there is an active tender
        return activeTender.noticeDocumentHash; // Return the IPFS hash of the notice document
    }
}

useContract hook in frontend(only for view function):
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import contractABI from "../../abi/e-procurement.json";

/**
 * Custom hook for interacting with the BidChain smart contract.
 * @param {string} contractAddress - Deployed contract address.
 * @returns {object} Object containing contract instance and helper methods.
 */

const useContract = (contractAddress) => {
    const [contract,setContract] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
         // Initialize the smart contract on mount

         const initializeContract = async () =>{
            try {
                const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
                const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(
                    contractAddress,
                    contractABI,
                    provider
                );

                setContract(contractInstance);

                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error initializing contract:", error);
            }
         };

         initializeContract();

    },[contractAddress]);

    return {contract};
     
};

export default useContract;

useContract2 hook in frontend (only for function where transaction occurs)
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import contractABI from "../../abi/e-procurement.json";

/**
 * Custom hook for interacting with the BidChain smart contract.
 * @param {string} contractAddress - Deployed contract address.
 * @returns {object} Object containing contract instance and helper methods.
 */

const useContract2 = (contractAddress) => {
    const [contract,setContract] = useState(null);
    const [currentNonce,setCurrentNonce] = useState(null);
 

    useEffect(() => {
         // Initialize the smart contract on mount

         const initializeContract = async () =>{
            try {

                const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
                const signer = await provider.getSigner();
                const address = await signer.getAddress(); // Get the wallet address
                const currentNonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(address);
                const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(
                    contractAddress,
                    contractABI,
                    signer
                );

             
                setContract(contractInstance);
                setCurrentNonce(currentNonce);
               

                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error initializing contract:", error);
            }
         };

         initializeContract();

    },[contractAddress]);

    return {contract,currentNonce};
     
};

export default useContract2;

registration.js where a transaction function (submitRegistrationRequest) is run successfully
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { connectWallet, getProvider} from "@/utils/connectWallet";
import useContract2 from "@/hooks/useContract2"; // Import your custom hook
import styles from "@/styles/Registration.module.css";
import { Router, useRouter } from "next/router";

const RegistrationPage = () => {
  const { contract,currentNonce} = useContract2("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3"); 
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");
  const [networkName, setNetworkName] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    companyName: Yup.string()
      .required("Company name is required")
      .min(3, "Company name must be at least 3 characters long"),
    email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email("Invalid email format"),
  });

  const handleConnectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      const address = await connectWallet();
      setWalletAddress(address);

      const provider = getProvider();
      const network = await provider.getNetwork();
      setNetworkName(network.name);
      toast.success("Wallet connected successfully!");

      

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error connecting wallet:", error.message);
      toast.error("Error connecting wallet: " + error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    try {
      if (!contract) {
        toast.error("Contract is not available. Please connect your wallet.");
        return;
      }

        // Check if currentNonce is available
        if(currentNonce === undefined)
        {
          toast.error("Unable to retrieve the current nonce.");
          return;
        }
        // Use the currentNonce for the transaction
        const tx = await contract.submitRegistrationRequest(values.companyName, values.email,{
          nonce: currentNonce, // Include the nonce in the transaction options
        });
        await tx.wait();

      toast.success("Registration request submitted successfully!");
      router.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting registration request:", error);
        if (error.data && error.data.message && error.data.message.includes("Registration request already submitted")) {
          toast.error("You have already submitted a registration request.");
        } else {
          toast.error("Failed to submit registration request.");
        }
    } finally {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container} flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen`}>
      <div className={`${styles.card} w-full max-w-lg shadow-lg rounded-lg`}>
        <h1 className={`${styles.title} text-3xl font-extrabold text-center mb-6`}>Bidder Registration</h1>

        <div className="text-center mb-6">
          <button
            onClick={handleConnectWallet}
            className={`${styles.button} mb-4`}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: walletAddress ? "green" : "orangered",
              color: "white",
            }}
          >
            {walletAddress ? "Wallet Connected" : "Connect Wallet"}
          </button>
          {walletAddress && <p><strong>Wallet Address:</strong> {walletAddress}</p>}
          {networkName && <p><strong>Connected Network:</strong> {networkName}</p>}
        </div>

        <Formik
          initialValues={{ companyName: "", email: "" }}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          {({ isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form className={`${styles.form} space-y-6`}>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="companyName" className={`${styles.label} block font-semibold mb-2`}>
                  Company Name
                </label>
                <Field
                  type="text"
                  id="companyName"
                  name="companyName"
                  className={`${styles.input}`}
                  placeholder="Enter your company name"
                />
                <ErrorMessage name="companyName" component="div" className={`${styles.error}`} />
              </div>

              <div>
                <label htmlFor="email" className={`${styles.label} block font-semibold mb-2`}>
                  Email Address
                </label>
                <Field
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  className={`${styles.input}`}
                  placeholder="Enter your email address"
                />
                <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className={`${styles.error}`} />
              </div>

              <div>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className={`${styles.button}`}
                  disabled={isSubmitting || !walletAddress}
                >
                  {isSubmitting ? "Submitting..." : "Register"}
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrationPage;

Now the issue lies in the showRegRequest.js file.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useContract from "@/hooks/useContract"; // Import your custom hook
import styles from "@/styles/ShowRegReq.module.css";
import useContract2 from '@/hooks/useContract2';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const ShowRegRequest = () => {
  const { contract } = useContract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3"); // Smart contract address
  const {contract2,currentNonce} = useContract2("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3");
  const [pendingContractors, setPendingContractors] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [approving, setApproving] = useState(false);
 
  // Fetch pending contractors from the contract
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPendingContractors = async () => {
      if (contract) {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          // Call the getPendingContractors function
          const contractors = await contract.getPendingContractors();
          setPendingContractors(contractors);
        } catch (err) {
          toast.error("Error fetching pending contractors:", err);
          console.error("Error fetching pending contractors:", err);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchPendingContractors();
  }, [contract]);

    // Approve contractor function
    const approveContractor = async(address) => {

      if (!contract) {
        toast.error("Contract not initialized or account not connected");
        console.error("Contract not initialized or account not connected");
        return;
      }

      setApproving(true);

      try {
         const tx = await contract2.registerContractor(address,{
          nonce: currentNonce, // Include the nonce in the transaction options
        }); 
        await tx.wait();
        toast.success(`Contractor ${address}} approved successfully`);
        console.log(`Contractor ${address} approved successfully`);

         // Remove approved contractor from the list
        setPendingContractors((prev) =>
          prev.filter((contractor) => contractor.contractorAddress !== address)
        );
        
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error("Error approving contractor");
        console.error(error);
      }

      finally {
        setApproving(false);
      }

    };


  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>Pending Contractor Requests</h1>

    {loading ? (
      <p className={styles.loading}>Loading...</p>
    ) : (
      <div className={styles.contractorsList}>
        {pendingContractors.length === 0 ? (
          <p>No pending contractors</p>
        ) : (
          pendingContractors.map((contractor, index) => (
            <div key={index} className={styles.contractorCard}>
              <p><strong>Name:</strong> {contractor.companyName}</p>
              <p><strong>Email:</strong> {contractor.email}</p>
              <p><strong>Account:</strong> {contractor.contractorAddress}</p>
              <button className={styles.approveButton}
              onClick={() => approveContractor(contractor.contractorAddress)}
              disabled={approving}
              >
              {approving ? "Approving..." : "Approve"}
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
  )
}

export default ShowRegRequest

Here whenever I try to click the "Approve"  button an error seems to occur

This is the status of the node terminal:

Can anyone help me solve this issue? I would greatly appreciate it. Sorry for my poor English.

The contract address that you're using (0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3) looks like a wallet address instead of a contract address on Ethereum Sepolia. Can you please check?

@SYED ASAD KAZMI brother, this is not the wallet address; rather, it is the deployed contract address when I am deploying it on the localhost network.
px hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/e-procurement.js --network localhost
Hardhat Ignition
Deploying [ EProcurementModule ]
Batch #1
Executed EProcurementModule#BidChain
[ EProcurementModule ] successfully deployed
Deployed Addresses
EProcurementModule#BidChain - 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3

Got it. So, if it’s the address of the contract on the localhost network, then how is your dApp interacting with that contract, as hardhat ignition doesn’t run a local node and provide its RPC explicitly?

This is the hardhat.config.js
module.exports = {
solidity: "0.8.27",
defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
networks: {
hardhat: {
chainId: 31337,
},
localhost: {
chainId: 31337,
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/"
},
sepolia: {
url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
chainId: 11155111,
blockConfirmations: 6,
saveDeployments: true,
},
},
};
@SYED ASAD KAZMI brother here I explicitly provided the RPC in localhost network .

Can you share your project via GitHub repo?

https://github.com/shureedshazzad/BlockChain-Based-E-Procurement-System
here it is brother

Brother, I have solved my problem. The issue primarily arose due to redundancy and inconsistency between the two hooks (useContract and useContract2) I was using. I have decided to use only a single useContract hook for both view and transaction functions. Initially, I thought that in order to execute a view function, I needed to use the provider with the contract instance. However, upon further review, I have realized that the signer can also be used for executing view functions instead of just the provider.
Thank you for your support.
